# how to resample state change data for line chart?

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to parse bugzilla data to create bug state change charts. I have setup mock [dataframe](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/T0MASD/2d27c9dcd6e094072351/raw/becc891b53594f9aaa786cafc1b626e49f4523c6/pandas%20rollup). I tried using:

```
df = df.set_index('bug_when')
df.resample('1D',how='count')
```

above gives total number of bugs for each day. I suppose I could setup new dataframes based on what was added **df.loc[df['added'] == 'NEW']** and use .resample, but I'm not sure how do I manage entries that have been removed and entries that haven't change since the day before.

I would really appreciate if anyone could please tell me what steps I need to make to process my dataframe so it looks something like this`

```
1998-11-01 : { 'NEW' : [1] }
1998-11-02 : { 'NEW' : [1,2] }
1998-11-03 : { 'NEW' : [2], 'CLOSED': [1] }
1998-11-04 : { 'NEW' : [3], 'CLOSED': [1,2] }
1998-11-05 : { 'NEW' : [], 'CLOSED': [1,2,3] }
```

Can I do this in pandas or do I need to create loops?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very useful to create a series that every cell is a dict object. You can make a table
that shows the status of every bug for every day, here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tslib import Timestamp
from pandas import DataFrame

data = [
{u'bug_id': 1, u'bug_when': Timestamp('1998-11-01 21:56:09'), u'removed': '', u'added': 'NEW'},
{u'bug_id': 2, u'bug_when': Timestamp('1998-11-02 14:20:17'), u'removed': '', u'added': 'NEW'},
{u'bug_id': 1, u'bug_when': Timestamp('1998-11-03 22:02:25'), u'removed': u'NEW', u'added': u'CLOSED'},
{u'bug_id': 3, u'bug_when': Timestamp('1998-11-04 10:02:01'), u'removed': u'', u'added': u'NEW'},
{u'bug_id': 2, u'bug_when': Timestamp('1998-11-04 10:02:02'), u'removed': u'NEW', u'added': u'CLOSED'},
{u'bug_id': 3, u'bug_when': Timestamp('1998-11-05 15:03:21'), u'removed': u'NEW', u'added': u'CLOSED'},
{u'bug_id': 4, u'bug_when': Timestamp('1998-11-05 16:03:21'), u'removed': u'NEW', u'added': u'NEW'},
{u'bug_id': 4, u'bug_when': Timestamp('1998-11-05 17:03:21'), u'removed': u'NEW', u'added': u'CLOSED'}
]

df = DataFrame(data=data, columns=['bug_id','bug_when','removed','added'])
df.set_index("bug_when", inplace=True)
```

If you only want open bug count for every day:

```
count = df.added.map({"NEW":1, "CLOSED":-1}).cumsum().resample("D", how="last")
print count
```

output:

```
bug_when
1998-11-01    1
1998-11-02    2
1998-11-03    1
1998-11-04    1
1998-11-05    0
Freq: D, Name: added, dtype: int64
```

If you want a table for every bug:

```
def f(s):
    s = s.resample("D", fill_method="ffill")
    s[:-1] = 1
    s[-1] = 0
    return s

df.groupby("bug_id")["bug_id"].apply(f).unstack(0).ffill()
```

output:

```
bug_id      1   2   3   4
bug_when                 
1998-11-01  1 NaN NaN NaN
1998-11-02  1   1 NaN NaN
1998-11-03  0   1 NaN NaN
1998-11-04  0   0   1 NaN
1998-11-05  0   0   0   0
```

1 means the bug is open at the date, 0 means the bug is closed at the date, NaN means the bug doesn't exist at the date.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, I wasn't aware of .map function, that's great. One thing to note tough, is that status change is recorded in removed column, bug status doesn't always change from new to closed so just using `added` column would be inaccurate.
I was wondering if it's possible to chain the following expression?
`df.added.map({"NEW":1})
df.removed.map({"NEW":-1})`
I would then like to combine the two in single row and run `.resample("1D", how="count")`

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Something along the lines of:
`df.added.map({"NEW":1}).fillna(df.removed.map({"NEW":-1})).cumsum().resample("1D", how="last")`
works ok, but I'm not sure if that's easy to read